# $m^*(A)=0$ then there exists Borel measurable sets $B$ and $C$ such that $A=B-C$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $m^*$ be the Lebesgue outer measure. 
If $A\subset R$ and $m^*(A)=0$ then there exists Borel measurable sets $B$ and $C$ such that $A=B- C$.

Can I say:

Since $m^*(A)=0$, $A$ must be a union of a bunch of singletons, which makes $A$ Borel measurable. Also, since $m^*(A)=0$ there exists some Borel measurable $B$ such that $A \subset B$. Lastly, since the collection of Borel-measurable sets is a sigma-algebra, $C=B \cap A^c$ is also Borel-mesurable.

Comment: "Since $m^*(A)=0$, $A$ must be a union of a bunch of singletons, which makes $A$ Borel measurable." False. Only countable union preserves measurability.

Comment: Any set is a union of a bunch of singletons.  It needn't, however, be a *countable* union of a bunch of singleton sets.  Indeed, there are many examples of uncountable sets with zero measure.  Also, what is $B/C$?

Comment: Set subtraction is usually written $B \setminus C$ or $B - C$.

Comment: What makes you think the statement is true?

Comment: You're right. What if I construct $B$ to be the union of {${(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) | x\in A}$}. Then B is a union of intervals which is a Borel set, and $B-A$ is also a union of some intervals. Does this make sense?

Comment: This can't be right... If $A = B\setminus C$ with $B,C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $A$ must be a Borel set (since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is closed with respect to complements and intersections).  But then every set with zero Lebesgue outer measure must be Borel, which is contradicted by the existence of Lebesgue measurable sets which are not Borel measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. Any set is the union of  a "bunch" of singletons. Perhaps you suppose (incorrectly) that if $m^*(A)=0$ then the bunch must be countable.  The set-difference $B\setminus C$ of two Borel sets $B,C$ is also a Borel set. But not every $A$ such that $m^*(A)=0$ is a Borel set.

The cardinal of the family of all Borel sets is $c=2^{\aleph_0},$ which is the cardinal of $\Bbb R.$  The Cantor set $D$ has cardinal $c$ and is a Borel set, and $m^*(D)=0,$ so $m^*(E)=0$ for any $E\subset D .$ But the cardinal of $\{E: E\subset D\}$ is $2^c,$ which is larger than $c.$ So there are non-Borel subsets of $D$ that have outer measure $0.$

There seems to be a teaching style that avoids mentioning $inner$  measure. The inner measure $m^i(A)$ of $A\subset \Bbb R$ can be defined as $\sup \{m^*(F): F=\overline F\subset A\}.$  Then $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable iff $m^*(A)=m^i(A)$....  iff there exist Borel sets $A',A''$ such that $A'\subset A\subset A''$ and $m^*(A')=m^*(A'')$ ....iff there are $G,H$ such that $A=G\cup H$ where $G$ is Borel and $m^*(H)=0$.

The family $\Bbb B$ of Borel sets is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets. The family $\Bbb L$ of Lebesgue sets is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra  that has $\Bbb B$ as a subset and which contains every set that has Lebesgue outer measure  $0.$.... The idea was to extend Borel measure to  a countably-additive, translation-invariant measure for which any subset of a measure-$0$ set is also measurable (with measure $0$ of course.)